# How to update post with multiple images in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I am a beginner with django rest framework, I have this code to update a post with multiple images, but uploading multiple images is not working properly and the image is not getting saved. While creating the post I was able to make the multiple upload part work fine. How can I make this serializer take in multiple images?

Thank you! Help will be much appreciated.

serializer

```
class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = ['id', 'images',]

class PostUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True))
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id','title', 'image', 'images',] #images is from another model POSTIMAGE

    def validate(self, post):
        try:
            title = post['title']
            image = post['image']
            images = post['images']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return post
```

views.

```
def update_post_api_view(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    if request.method == 'PUT': 
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        user = request.user
        if post.user != user:
            return Response({'response': "You can't edit the post!"})

        serializer = PostUpdateSerializer(post, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data = {
            'success': 'update successful',
            }
            return Response(data=data)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is the model..

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/postimage/', null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Posted")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255)

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/postimage/')
```

Comment: How does your `Post` and `PostImage` models look like?

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question with both models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the **`update(...)`** method of the **`PostUpdateSerializer`** serializer class

```
class PostUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True))

    def clear_existing_images(self, instance):
        for post_image in instance.postimage_set.all():
            post_image.images.delete()
            post_image.delete()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        images = validated_data.pop('images', None)
        if images:
            # self.clear_existing_images(instance) # uncomment this if you want to clear existing images.
            post_image_model_instance = [PostImage(post=instance, images=image) for image in images]
            PostImage.objects.bulk_create(
                post_image_model_instance
            )
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'image', 'images', ]
```

By default, this **`update()`** method ***append images*** to the existing posts.

You can use **`clear_existing_images(...)`** method to clear existing images from the database as well as from storage location.

### Update-1

to limit the images, use **`max_length`** argument as

```
serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True), max_length=2)
```

Comment: Thank you..Should I remove the validation function inside the update serializer?

Comment: Is it possible to limit the number of images being uploaded..like how we do with inline or modalforms?

Comment: yes, you should remove the validation function as it is doing nothing there.

Comment: Check the `update-1` section to see how you can limit the images.

Comment: Hello @Arakkal Abu
if you don't mind can you please have a look at this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361830/is-this-the-correct-way-to-add-post-to-favourites-using-django-rest-framework

Thanks