# Is this the correct way to add post to favourites using django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a doubt regarding django rest framework for this function. I have done it the same way I do in a normal django website.
can someone please check and tell me whether this is the right way to do it using django rest framework so that, this can be used to connect to a front end later..

view

```
def favourite_post_api(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    user = request.user
    serializer = PostSerializer(post)
    if user in post.favourite.all():
        post.favourite.remove(user)
        return Response("Removed from favourites.", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        post.favourite.add(user)
        return Response("Added to favourites.", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/postimage/', null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Posted")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Updated")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='post_likes', blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='post_favourite', blank=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey, actually the above code works without any errors in postman. but I wanted to know whether this is the right way to do it..?

Comment: Can you share `Post` Model with us? We need a little more information, but you're almost there.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question with models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I will show you my approach for your case:

views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class PostView(APIView):
    bad_request_message = 'An error has occurred'

    def post(self, request):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=request.data.get('slug'))
        if request.user not in post.favourite.all():
            post.favourite.add(request.user)
            return Response({'detail': 'User added to post'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'detail': self.bad_request_message}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=request.data.get('slug'))
        if request.user in post.favourite.all():
            post.favourite.remove(request.user)
            return Response({'detail': 'User removed from post'}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return Response({'detail': self.bad_request_message}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
import yourapp.views as views

urlpatterns = [
    path('dummy-path/', views.PostView.as_view()),
]
```

What you need to do now is sent a `json` like `{"slug": "your_data"}` on `/dummy-path` url using the `POST` method for add user or `DELETE` method for user removal.

Comment: Thank you for the response. but should there be 2 separate urls for the delete and post functions?

Comment: Ok. let me try it and get back to you.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.  You can test that endpoint by creating unit tests, and you can see it working using an application like https://insomnia.rest/

Comment: wow..Thanks for that. never knew about these before.